# How do I collapse a multi-column data.frame into a single text string capturing information row by row?

Tags: r, dplyr

The goal is to take some plot data and then put the latest points in the caption as a string.

My toy data is:

```
df <- data.frame (state=c("buy", "sell"), freq=c(0.102, .801))
```

so it looks like this:

```
> df
  state  freq
1   buy 0.102
2  sell 0.801
```

I want to get the string:

```
mystring <- "buy 10.2%, sell 80.1%"
```

So I want first row state1 with freq1 then second row state2 with freq2.

I have tried unlisting and paste with collapse but no luck yet. Apart from looping over every row is there a smarter dplyr/tidyverse way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

str_glue_data(df, "{state} {freq*100}%") |>
  str_flatten_comma()
# [1] "buy 10.2%, sell 80.1%"
```

Comment: And thinking out of the box. like it!

Comment: how do you round for formats? so 0.56679 is 56.7%

Comment: @micstr `{round(freq*100, 1)}`

Answer (score 1):

You can first paste every row and then collapse it in the end:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- data.frame (state=c("buy", "sell"), freq=c(0.102, .801))

df %>% 
  mutate(together = paste0(state, " ", freq * 100, "%")) %>% 
  pull(together) %>% 
  paste0(collapse = ", ")
#> [1] "buy 10.2%, sell 80.1%"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could use `pmap_vec`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
   mutate(freq = paste0(round(freq * 100, 1), "%")) %>% 
   pmap_vec(paste, sep = " ") %>% 
   paste(collapse = ", ")
```

```
[1] "buy 10.2%, sell 80.1%"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my cheesy loop method which I am trying to avoid:

```
my_str <- ""
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  my_str <- paste0(my_str, 
                   df[row, "state"], " ", df[row, "freq"])
  if (row < nrow(df)) {
    my_str <- paste0(my_str, ", ")
  }
}

> my_str
[1] "buy 0.102, sell 0.801"
```